# Webservice only accessible from localhost?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, web-services

I'm trying to get JSON back from a webservice through a jQuery ajax call that points to my MVC5 controller. When I run it locally in Visual Studio (2013) it works fine, however I get errors whenever I deploy it to a server. The webservice is a cloud based service.

I can't figure out the issue?

When I try to grab the error from the fail function in JS I simply get "error", "Not found"?

**Code**

Controller:

```
public string GetJson2()
    {
        string url = "*private*";
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            //JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = client.DownloadString(url);
            //var tracks = jss.Deserialize<Tracks>(json);
            //string output = jss.Serialize(tracks);
            // TODO: do something with the model
            return json;
        }
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON("/Home/GetJson2")
.done(function (data) {
    var string = "<table>";
    var tbody = "";
    var count = 0;
    var header = "<tr>";
    // On success, 'data' contains a list of documents.
    $.each(data, function () {
        tbody += "<tr>";
        $.each(this, function (k, v) {
            if (count == 0) { header += "<th>" + k + "</th>"; }
            tbody += "<td>" +  v + "</td>";
        });
        tbody += "</tr>";
        count += 1;
    });
    header += "</tr>";
    var table = string + header + tbody;
    table += "</table>";
    $("#results").html(table);
})
.fail(function (x, y, z) { alert(x); alert(y); alert(z); });
```

Let me know if I need to supply anything else!

Thanks!

**Update**

This seems to be more an MVC problem than a webservice problem, as when I navigate directly to the above controller in the browser I get a 404 page, so it seems I haven't configured something correctly? Once again, I can navigate directly in localhost, just not on the server.

**Update 2**

I resolved the routing issue and am now receiving a 500 error when I try to get data from the webservice. Once again... works just fine locally. I am now shooting in the dark.

Comment: is the http response code a 404? perhaps DNS isn't properly set up to point at the remote server.

Comment: I do get a 404 from the call to the controller. How would I setup the DNS to point at a remote server?

Comment: First try using the same url in a browser and see what the server says. Did you deploy to the root of the site, or a virtual website under the domain? (as your URL is root relative)

Comment: When I go straight to the controller in the browser ie: "http://mydomain/GetJson2" I get a 404. If I do the same in localhost it works. Why would that work in localhost but not when deployed?

Comment: When you are deploying it in any server, make sure all other resources are kept accordingly not just only code files. Check the war file and if needed add it manually.

Comment: All files are kept, I just verified.